# EMS packages opened at border?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, scams, mail, drugs

Do packages get opened at the border from Canada to US and do they charge a $2950 wire transfer fee they say is refundable.

Comment: This does not appear to be a question about travel.

Comment: Hopefully you understand there isn't much information in your post (could you attach whatever you have been told, and what is ems?) But it does sound possible this is a scam - are you expecting anything? I'd recommend being careful, thinking very hard and verifying everything independently (Don't phone a number of the letter, Google for one) before sending any money.

Comment: EMS is Express Mail Service. *Who* is proposing to open their packages at the border, and *who* is proposing to charge a fee? In the case of DHL the package would be checked and sealed before leaving its warehouse.

Comment: Sounds like a scam. Sometimes a customs office will check packages and demand tariffs on valuable imports or gifts, but then they **won't** specify a payment method and they **won't** promise to give the money back. So this is not legit. If you transfer the money, you won't see it again.